# pytz adding extra minutes

Tags: datetime, timezone, pytz

What's the difference between US/Mountain and AZ timezone. Why is it adding an extra **28 min**?

```
>>> strtime = datetime.datetime.strptime('10:00pm', '%I:%M%p')
>>> tz = timezone('US/Mountain').localize(strtime)
>>> print tz
1900-01-01 22:00:00-07:00
>>> tz = timezone(us.states.lookup('AZ').capital_tz).localize(strtime)
>>> print tz
1900-01-01 22:00:00-07:28 <<-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is most likely due to the fact that your year is 1900 (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056110/python-pytz-timezone-conversion-returns-values-that-differ-from-timezone-offset) question); it works fine if you add a current year:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import us

strtime = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020 10:00pm', '%Y %I:%M%p')
tz = timezone('US/Mountain').localize(strtime)
print(tz)
# 2020-01-01 22:00:00-07:00
tz = timezone(us.states.lookup('AZ').capital_tz).localize(strtime)
print(tz)
# 2020-01-01 22:00:00-07:00
```

(I'm using Python3 but that shouldn't make a difference, I get the same 28 min offset for year 1900)